# NSMergeConflict with encrypted CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, encryption

I am currently using an encrypted Coredata courtesy of Gavin Black (https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data) for my own project and I am running into SELECTIVE NSMergeConflict exceptions. I say selective on purpose as I am noticing it consistently fails for certain entities, and consistently functions as expected for other entities. The situation is as follows:

1. Clean install app and login
2. Upon login, I pull data down from cloud server (This works fine)
3. I access some of the data and attempt to pull more detailed information down from the cloud (this fails every time).

The exact error code I get is **Cocoa error 133020**

Things I have tried:

1. I've checked to ensure only the main thread is accessing/modifying Coredata
2. I've tried applying merge policies such as NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy to my MOC

I should note that prior to switching my PSC from the native NSSQLiteStoreType to the encrypted version, all entities were being pulled/inserted/modified/deleted properly with no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved by ensuring all Coredata operations are done on the main thread.